# Saving enumerated values to a database

Tags: sql, types, enums, go

I'm new to Go and I'm trying to write a little program to save enumerated values to a database.
The way I declare my values is as follows:

```
type FileType int64
const (
    movie FileType = iota
    music
    book
    etc
)
```

I use these values in my struct like this:

```
type File struct {
    Name     string
    Type     FileType
    Size     int64
}
```

I use gorp for my database stuff, but I guess the use of gorp isn't relevant to my problem. I put stuff in my DB like this:

```
dbmap.Insert(&File{"MyBook.pdf",movie,1000})
```

but when I try to retrieve stuff…

```
dbmap.Select(&dbFiles, "select * from Files")
```

I get the following error:

```
panic: reflect.Set: value of type int64 is not assignable to type main.FileType
```

When I use `int64` as the type for the `const(...)` and for the `File.Type` field, everything works fine, but I'm new to Go and want to understand the problem.
The way I see it, I have two problems:

1. Why can't Go convert this stuff successfully? I looked at the source code of the Go reflection and sql packages and there are methods for this kind of conversion, but they seem to fail. Is this a bug? What is the problem?
2. I figured out, that one can implement the `sql.Scanner` interface by implementing the following method:

   ```
   Scan(src interface{}) error
   ```

   I tried to implement the method and I even was able to get the right value from `src` and convert it to a `FileType`, but I was confused if I should implement the method for "`(f *FileType)` or `(f FileType)`. Either way the method gets invoked, however I'm not able to overwrite `f` (or at least the update gets lost later) and the `File` instances read from the DB always had a "0" as value for `File.Type`.

Do you have any ideas on those two points?

Comment: You really should not use an iota value outside the scope of Go, in for example the database. If you would ever re-order the constants, or add a new one in the middle, the iota values will change mismatching existing records in your database.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I recently had the same need, and the solution is to implement two interfaces:

1. [sql/driver.Valuer](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/driver/#Valuer)
2. [sql.Scanner](http://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#Scanner)

Here's a working example:

```
type FileType int64

func (u *FileType) Scan(value interface{}) error { *u = FileType(value.(int64)); return nil }
func (u FileType) Value() (driver.Value, error)  { return int64(u), nil }
```

Comment: This is the right answer and should be accepted.  Great job.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, I'm a total go newbie. Is there a good reason to make this an int64? It seems that you only need an int16 or even int8, since you're probably not going to have billions of possible values.

Comment: @bigblind it's what the original question used. I would typically not start worrying too much about value sizes until it becomes an issue, or the problem space warrants it.

Answer (score 9):

Slightly off-topic, but may be useful to others as I kept revisiting this question/answer when solving a similar problem when working with postgres enum fields in golang (which are returned as bytes).

```
 // Status values
 const ( 
     incomplete Status = "incomplete"
     complete   Status = "complete" 
     reject     Status = "reject"
 )

 type Status string

 func (s *Status) Scan(value interface{}) error {
     asBytes, ok := value.([]byte)
     if !ok {
         return errors.New("Scan source is not []byte")
     }
     *s = Status(string(asBytes))
     return nil
 }

 func (s SubjectStatus) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
     // validation would go here
     return string(s), nil
 }
```

Comment: Go doesn't have `enum`s. Your constants are of type `string`. If you want them to be of type `Status` (you do) then you should use `Incomplete Status = "incomplete"`, `Complete Status = "complete"`, etc (also, all-capital identifiers are not idiomatic Go).

Comment: @DaveC thanks, updated! Just to be clear, I'm referring to postgres' actual `enum` column type, but good corrections.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go needs to be specific with types, which can be a pain sometimes.
2. `(f FileType)` is cheaper than `(f *FileType)` for "native" types, pretty much unless you have a complex type, it's almost always better to not use a pointer.
3. What do you mean it doesn't overwrite it? did you resave the struct after you modified it?

Comment: regarding 2: ok, but how do i change "f" in case of "(f FileType)" when I write something like "f = book" in the Scan method, it has no effect.

Comment: You can only modify your value, if it operates on a pointer receiver. Have a look at the implementation of `sql.NullInt64` in the [stdlib](http://golang.org/src/pkg/database/sql/sql.go?s=2333:2382#L80).